# Python - count possible positions in a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

I have a range of given length *L* and 3 items (subranges) in it (*a, b, c*). Each item has a particular length. I want to count all possible arrangements of those three items in the range. Order does matter.

**Example:**

```
*L* = 10

*a, b, c* = 4,3,1
```

Doing it by hand I get 10 possible arrangements:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | a | a | b | b | b | c |  |  |
| a | a | a | a | b | b | b |  | c |  |
| a | a | a | a | b | b | b |  |  | c |
| a | a | a | a |  | b | b | b | c |  |
| a | a | a | a |  | b | b | b |  | c |
| a | a | a | a |  |  | b | b | b | c |
|  | a | a | a | a | b | b | b | c |  |
|  | a | a | a | a | b | b | b |  | c |
|  | a | a | a | a |  | b | b | b | c |
|  |  | a | a | a | a | b | b | b | c |

How may I list all those 10 possible solutions in Python? Let's assume the empty spaces are filled with zeros. So the output may look like this:

```
result = [['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 0, 0], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 0, 'c', 0], ...]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indexes (`i,j,k`) show where the index of the first element of a,b, and c characters starts.

Code:

```
def gen(L, a, b, c):
    arr = []
    for i in range(L - a - b - c + 1):         # i: index where 'a' starts
        for j in range(i + a, L - b - c + 1):  # j: index where 'b' starts
            for k in range(j + b, L - c + 1):  # k: index where 'c' starts
                print("i:", i, " j:", j, "k:", k)
                arr.append([0]*i + ['a']*a + [0]*(j-i-a) + ['b']*b + [0]*(k-j-b) + ['c']*c + [0]*(L-k-c))
    return arr

L = 10
a, b, c = 4, 3, 1
arr= gen(L, a, b, c)

for idx, arr in enumerate(arr, 1):
    print(f"{idx}: {arr}")
```

Output:

```
i: 0  j: 4 k: 7
i: 0  j: 4 k: 8
i: 0  j: 4 k: 9
i: 0  j: 5 k: 8
i: 0  j: 5 k: 9
i: 0  j: 6 k: 9
i: 1  j: 5 k: 8
i: 1  j: 5 k: 9
i: 1  j: 6 k: 9
i: 2  j: 6 k: 9
1: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 0, 0]
2: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 0, 'c', 0]
3: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 0, 0, 'c']
4: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 0, 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 0]
5: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 0, 'b', 'b', 'b', 0, 'c']
6: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 0, 0, 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
7: [0, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 0]
8: [0, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 0, 'c']
9: [0, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 0, 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
10: [0, 0, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```